# “in that time” or “at that time”

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, prepositional-phrases

Which is correct? "at that time" or "in that time" Here is the example sentence:

> In the summer in Beijing it is always hot, even during the Qing Dynasty. People **in/at** that time did not have air conditioning, so they...

Comment: Consider “*of* that time”.

Comment: There is nothing ungrammatical about either. Many more prepositions could also be used. It's a matter of personal opinion.

Comment: I wouldn't use either, I'd change the expression or rephrase it: 1. [**In those days**](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/in-those-days) 2. **in that [era](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/era)**, 3. *during that era/period*, 4. in the past 5. many centuries ago

Comment: I’d go for Peking. Certainly at that time that was the English.

Answer (score -1):

Generally speaking, "at" is used to refer to a point in time, while "in" refers to the time period after the present moment.

- I'll call you back **at** 5.30.
- I'll call you back **in** 10
  minutes.

If we apply the same logic to "that time", the following sentence seems coherent:

- I'll be cooking pasta for the next twenty minutes; could you please lay the table **in that time**?

So, I would definitely use **at that time** in the example sentence, as it refers to a point of time, not to the period starting now.

Answer (score -2):

I read a lot and I want to say it is "at that time" because it sounds better and has more of a cadence melodic harmonious feel to it.